# Making a list of lists from two lists based on indexes

Tags: python, loops, merge, logic

I have these two lists

```
indexes = [4, 2, 4, 6]
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I'm looking to merge these lists to be this. Each index value corresponds to the list size of the merge.

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

The current answer I have for this is okay, but I'm wondering if there's a better method for it.

```
ids = []
cIndex = 0
for i in indexes:
    ids.append([values[cIndex+x] for x in xrange(i)])
    cIndex += i
```

Comment: Your code produces `[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]]`, which is different from the list in question. What do you actually want?

Comment: You're correct my mistake!

Comment: Very similar to other questions.  See this answer in particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312467/560599 -- shouldn't be hard to generalize that for a list of sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use *list comprehension* expression with [*list slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) as:

```
>>> indexes = [4, 2, 4, 6]
>>> values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]

>>> [values[sum(indexes[:i]):sum(indexes[:i+1])] for i, index in enumerate(indexes)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @chribis : You should be careful while writing the questions and you shouldn't be changing the *basic requirement* of the question once you have the answers to it. It marks existing answers invalid answer. For example: I just got two down-votes because you changed your question :/ PS: I have updated the answer to match your desired result

Comment: Quite sorry, @Moinuddin. My mistake. I've accepted your answer.

Comment: I appreciate that, but accepting the answer is not an apology. You need to be careful while initially writing the question. Ideally I should have rollback your question to previous version. But since you are new here, I think you weren't knowing about it, and will be careful in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

A regular for loop is a readable solution to this. There's no need for the list comprehension though, just maintain the current position in the list for slicing.

```
def split(idxes, vals):
    res = []
    pos = 0
    for i in idxes:
        res.append(vals[pos:pos+i])
        pos += i
    return res
```

---

Or if you particularly feel like importing `itertools`, though it's not really needed here, you could take the cumulative sum of the indices and then use the `pairwise` recipe.

```
from itertools import accumulate, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Like so

```
>>> [values[beg:end] for beg, end in pairwise(accumulate([0]+indexes))]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
indexes = [4, 2, 4, 6]
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]

l=[]
l2=[]
j=0
for i in range(len(indexes)):
    k=0
    while k < indexes[i]:
        l.append(values[j])
        j+=1
        k+=1
    l2.append(l)
    l=[]

print(l2)

# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
```